# Half kth term if n is even and k=n/2?

Tags: functions, syntax, conditional

I am trying to write a function which will perform the equation in the attached image. So far, I have:

```
x[n_] :=
 x[n] =
  2^(1 - n) Sum[Binomial[n, k] T[n - 2 k], {k, 0, n/2}]

x[6]
```

which outputs:

$ \frac{1}{32} (20 T(0)+15 T(2)+6 T(4)+T(6)) $

How can I write an `If[]` (or similar) statement to half the `kth` term when `n` is even and `k=n/2`?
Thanks in advance!

[image: Equation 2.14]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:-

```
x[n_] :=
 x[n] =
  2^(1 - n) Sum[Binomial[n, k] T[n - 2 k]/If[EvenQ[n] && k == n/2, 2, 1],
    {k, 0, n/2}]

x[6]
```

> 1/32 (10 T[0] + 15 T[2] + 6 T[4] + T[6])

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a solution that makes use of pattern matching - the (to me) a little awkward phrasing 'if n is even and k=n/2 simply means the following:

In the case of even `n` (as `Floor[n/2] == n/2` if `EvenQ[n]==True`), run the sum to `n-1` (as `k==n/2` means 'the last term' in this case)  and add the last term (which is `2^(-n) Binomial[n, n/2]  T[0]` manually.

So:

```
x[n_] := 2^(1 - n) Sum[Binomial[n, k] T[n - 2 k], {k, 0, n/2}]
x[n_/; EvenQ[n]] := x[n-1] + 2^(-n) Binomial[n,n/2] T[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an elegant way is using `PieceWise`:

```
x[n_] := 2^(1 - n) Sum[
   Piecewise[{{1/2, EvenQ[n] && k == n/2}, {1, True}}] Binomial[n, k] T[n - 2 k], {k, 0, n/2}]
```

so the first six terms are:

```
x /@ Range[6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]